# Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, npm, npm-install

After I use `npm install` I get this error in this link below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVvps.jpg

I have this  problem today and i don't know why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These kind of problems could be happening when clashing react modules. 
Delete `node_module` folder and `package-lock.json` file. Then run again `npm  install`.

Comment: I always do that but this time it gave me this error, thanks for helping :)

Comment: you can go through log file that the error message says. Can you check them and post the descriptions